# Merge a collection using the same key values

Tags: laravel, collections

I have two collections with data to combine:

```
//1
  [
     [
       "date" => "2019-02-15",
       "clicks" => 1,
     ],
   ]
//2
[
     [
       "date" => "2019-02-15",
       "users" => 1,
     ],
   ]
```

it is necessary that the collection elements (arrays) that have the same values ​​for a particular key are combined

Comment: Have you tried $firstCollection + $secondCollection?

Comment: so are you sure that the two date values will be always the same?

Comment: in both collections there can be arrays with different dates in the date key.  I need to combine those that have the same

Comment: @DavidNadejdin have you tried the above solution? merging by + sign?

Comment: @Sehdev i don't think it will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

$c1 = collect([
    [
        "date" => "2019-02-15",
        "clicks" => 1,
    ],
    [
        "date" => "2019-02-16",
        "clicks" => 3,
    ],
]);

$c2 = collect([
    [
        "date" => "2019-02-15",
        "users" => 4,
    ],
    [
        "date" => "2019-02-16",
        "users" => 5,
    ],
]);

$c1->merge($c2)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->map(function ($items) {
        return Arr::collapse($items);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

$collectionOne = new Collection(['foo']);

$collectionTwo = new Collection(['bar']);

$collection = $collectionOne->merge($collectionTwo);

Comment: As per Laravel Documentation: The merge method merges the given array or collection with the original collection. If a string key in the given items matches a string key in the original collection, the given items's value will overwrite the value in the original collection
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge

Comment: both arrays are originally collections and I need to not just combine them